# Delay in programmatically displaying a view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, viewcontroller

**RESOLVED**

I was performing the segue from inside a block and it was another thread. When I specifically move the operation back to the main thread it works great.

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LoadToDisplay" sender:self];
}];
```

**QUESTION**

I want to programmatically present a view controller.

My app downloads some data from the internet, carries out some data handling and then loads the next view.

I use performSegueWithIdentifer successfully throughout the rest of the app however for some reason it is adding a huge delay with this specific transition.

I've used presentViewController with no delay but I can't use this, it was just to test whether I was missing something obvious.

I have an NSLog when the last data handling method completes and one when the next view controller is loaded. Using 'presentViewController' the time between logs is 14ms. When using performSegueWithIdentifer is a staggering 8.5secs!

I literally commented out one line and tested with the other. No other code changes.

Has anyone else experienced this or know what might be going on?

Thanks.

Comment: What does the viewController you want to show? Do you load datas in willAppear method? Or in viewDidLoad?

Comment: I think you should check your destination view controllers view did load or view will appear methods. There might be some functionality that is taking time to load your destination view controller.

Comment: I've now found the answer whilst searching for another issue. I was trying to move from inside a block and needed to move the operation back to the main queue. It now all works fine.

Comment: It's totally fine to answer your own question. But please don't add the answer to your question. Instead add an answer below and click the tickmark once you submitted it.